# how to download gta san andreas on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wine

i wanna a download link of grand theft auto san andreas version linux ubuntu 12.04 please anyone give me a download link of mta san andres and gta san andreas version linux ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

first of all search for san andread on POL[play on linux which is a open source application available in software centre] if you find it over there then you can just install the game using a live cd or dvd but in case if it is not available on POL you can use ps2 emulator or wine to play those games

if you are using wine then follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4nfmmOL1Dc)

Comment: where is the file in this website : http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=0&iItemsPerPage=25

Answer (score 2):

- [Download link](http://www.rockstarwarehouse.com/Details/rs-gta010frpc0fg01) (9.99$).

You'll need Wine or PlayOnLinux to run it, without any guarantee it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Wine, but I am pretty sure you just install the game and run the .exe through Wine? If you don't have wine, and there isn't a Linux version of the game you can't run it on Ubuntu.